# Get articles and comments with only one SQL query ? (one to many relation)

Tags: sql

I have one table named 'articles' and other one linked with it named 'comments'.

articles ------------ comments

Is there a SQL query to get all articles and their comments linked with it ?

```
articles1
  +------ comment1
  +------ comment2
  +------ comment3
articles2
  +------- comment4
  +------- comment5
```

Thanks

Comment: If you want articles with no comments returned as well, use a left outer join instead of an inner Join. Otherwise..Abe's Query below should fit your needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a JOIN would fit your needs:

```
SELECT * FROM Articles as a
INNER JOIN comments as c
ON a.articleId = c.ArticleId
```

Take a look at [this article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).  It gives the best explanation of JOINS that I have seen.

Comment: Thanks ! And how can I do to select also articles without comments ?

Answer (score 0):

You failed to post more details about your tables, but here is a blind guess from my side:

```
SELECT articles.*, 
       comments.comment
FROM articles 
   JOIN comments ON comments.article_id = articles.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Stackexchange query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1270/post-with-comments) that lists posts with its Comments. You'll notice its uses
a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  top 100 p.id [Post Link], p.id, c.id, c.text from posts p
LEFT JOIN comments c
on p.id = c.postid
```

This is because every post is not guaranteed to have a Comment